# removing repeated rows in a text file in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset like the following example:

```
0.0081967213    GCLC
0.0081967213    GCLC
0.0115273775    NFYA
0.0115273775    NFYA
0.0348432056    STPG1
0.0348432056    STPG1
0.0348432056    STPG1
```

and I would like to make a new file like this:

```
0.0081967213    GCLC
0.0115273775    NFYA
0.0348432056    STPG1
```

meaning I would like to have one repeat of each line.  I actually tried

```
data <- read.table("file.txt", sep=",")
 data2 <- unique(data)
```

but did not return what I wanted. do you know to make such file?

Comment: Try `?duplicated`.

Comment: @Sotos: I did not find the same question. can you give the link?